# How to install python 2.7?

Tags: 10.10, installation, python

I have some troubles installing python2.7 on ubuntu 10.10
I ran `sudo apt-get install python2.7`(*) but when I try to run an example program
I get the

```
 ~/Downloads% python2.7 clockwindow.py
 Traceback (most recent call last):  
 File "clockwindow.py", line 1, in
 <module>
     import pygtk ImportError: No module named pygtk
```

error messages, so what's the best way to install python and its modules?

Answer (score 3):

It looks like there are a few broken or missing things regarding pygtk with Python2.7 under Maverick (pygobject-dev maybe).

Unless you really need Python2.7, you will save yourself a lot of stress using the Python2.6 version of pygtk included in Maverick.